# Kaltura server and player integration

Tags: kaltura

I am getting started with working on videos. The requirement is to be able to have videos with preroll/midroll/postroll ads. We are looking at kaltura since it supports VPAID 3.0 as well. 
I am completely new to video streaming as well as VAST and VPAID standards. However, looking at the vast documentation on player.kaltura.com, the knowledge center and the developer portal am fairly confused as to where to start from. I want to be able to upload videos to the kaltura server and have them work with ads on kaltura player. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can configure the ads via Player Studio in you KMC. The ads configuration is per player

Comment: Thanks! I was able to configure the ads :)